# How to implement one to one chat through Pubnub?

Tags: android, pubnub

I want to implement one to one chat by using pubnub.

I googled it, all code related to group chat.

Based some info for one to one ,i need to create dynamic channels for each user.

I created channels for each user.and sent and received one to one chat,based on dynamic subscribe and un subscribe.

But my question is how to get the list off all channels.

How to find the presence of each channel.

If any one know the solution ,Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All of your questions are in the docs. But hereNow with no channel will give you all active channels and users on those channels. But do you want a list of all channels or just the ones that the user is on? Provide more details about your requirments.

Comment: @kiran, I am also facing the same problem. Could you please tell me how you created channel for each user .and sent and received one to one chat,based on dynamic subscribe and un subscribe.?

Comment: I also want to know how to create one to one and one to many channels dynamic are you using email combination to create a channel or anything else if email then how can you check receiver to send a message whether he is on the same channel or need to create one .

Comment: @CraigConover - could you guide to specific example in the documentation. There should be a simple sample for one to one chat which is lacking in pubnub documentation. How do I get the list of all users (or list of one to one channels) I have chatted with? Once I getthat list how do I show the count of unread messages in each channel. Should not we have a simple code demo for the very normal one to one chat?

Comment: @user2645830 - please submit email to support@pubnub.com with your inquiry. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## One-to-one PubNub Chat

How to implement one to one chat through PubNub?  Here are some resource links to get started:

- http://angularjs.chat/tutorials/angularjs-basic-chat-module/
- https://github.com/pubnub/open-chat-framework

These frameworks make it easier to get started building your mobile chat app.